# Visual Studio 2010 SDK won't install with VS 11 Developer Preview Present

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Trying to install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK but it aborts with an error saying I don't have Visual Studio 2010 installed. I of course have 2010 installed. I also have the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview installed. I suspect this might be the issue. Is this known? Is there a workaround (I couldn't find one). Running on Windows 7, 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that there is an *SDK* and and *SDK SP1*. If you have *VS 2010 SP1* installed (like I have) then only the *VS 2010 SDK SP1* will install. Easy as that and nothing to do with VS 11 as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's always recommended to install your oldest version of Visual Studio first and move on up to your newest.  Uninstall 11 first, then install 2010, and then install 11. You might have better luck than you have so far.

Good luck, and hope this helps.

Comment: Are you suggesting the *SDK* should be installed before VS 11?

Comment: I'm just saying that there are different dependencies for each, and starting with the lower one first and moving up to the newer one usually gets you around installation issues.